# Flutter app w/ Firebase Auth and Revenue cat's IAP not connecting

Tags: ios, firebase, flutter

So I'm facing a really odd problem and don't really know where to look.

I have a an app built in flutter. I'm using Bitrise for CI/CD. I had the configuration set to use XCode 11 until yesterday. I didn't notice that it needed changing till I got the message saying I needed to build using the iOS 14 SDK. I upgraded the stack, and was able to publish a build to testflight.

I set the version to use XCode 12.5 (latest). The app would be asking to log in again after re-opening and would get an error saying in app purchases could not be loaded. Error code: 21004

This only happens on testflight builds. Local builds using XCode 12.5 can handle IAP and firebase auth just fine. I can't attach a debugger to a testflight build.

I decided since the only difference is XCode, I'll back down to 12.4, and that seem to solve the IAP problem, but the app is still logged out every time it opens. The saved user profile on the local db is just fine. Just firebase thinks it's logged out.

Error loggs are unhelpful. The only thing I've managed to find is

```
default    13:45:20.643023-0600    photoanalysisd    PLAccountStore accountDidChange, clearing cached properties.
default    13:45:20.643750-0600    assetsd    PLAccountStore accountDidChange, clearing cached properties.
default    13:45:20.644216-0600    backboardd     [1.26.0]     +[ASEProcessing shouldEnhanceWidth:height:destinationWidth:destinationHeight:]: src={ 1242w x 2688h }, dest={ 1240w x 2683h }, aseFunctionOnYesOffNo=1
default    13:45:20.645602-0600    fitcored    [1031] <private>::<private>
default    13:45:20.645884-0600    assetsd    photoStreamAccountSettingsChanged
default    13:45:20.646817-0600    assetsd    Clearing cached PLPhotoSharingHelper state
default    13:45:20.646867-0600    ptpd    PLAccountStore accountDidChange, clearing cached properties.
default    13:45:20.647514-0600    wifid    -[WiFiAccountStoreManager _updateIsManagedAppleIDAndNotify:]_block_invoke: No change Current (Non-Managed Account)
default    13:45:20.648268-0600    accountsd    "<private> (<private>) received"
default    13:45:20.648443-0600    appstored    elided platform fast path for key: re6Zb+zwFKJNlkQTUeT+/w
default    13:45:20.648542-0600    accountsd    "<private> (<private>) received"
default    13:45:20.648829-0600    accountsd    "<private> (<private>) received"
default    13:45:20.649444-0600    appstored    AMSMescal: [IAPF9A5435D/[MY APP]:2_1] Skipping mescal - unabled to locate data to sign
error    13:45:20.649481-0600    appstored    AMSURLRequest: [IAPF9A5435D/[MY APP]:2_1] Failed to add mescal header. Error: Error Domain=AMSErrorDomain Code=204 "Bag Value Missing" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Bag Value Missing, NSLocalizedFailureReason=The bag does not contain signed-actions nor did anyone register a default value. <AMSBagNetworkDataSource: 0x104e18ff0; profile: appstored; version: 1; sandbox: 1>}
default    13:45:20.649516-0600    appstored    AMSURLSession: [IAPF9A5435D/[MY APP]:2_1] Preparing request: <AMSURLRequest: 0x1051bcd90> { URL: https://sandbox.itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZFinance.woa/wa/inAppPendingTransactions?guid=00008030-001A20E83C78802E }
default    13:45:20.649678-0600    appstored    AMSURLSession: [IAPF9A5435D/[MY APP]:2_1] Task created: LocalDataTask <B3B892EF-AF0E-4185-AFE5-A28937F04BD8>.<2> Session: <__NSURLSessionLocal: 0x10762d2b0>
default    13:45:20.649717-0600    appstored    Task <B3B892EF-AF0E-4185-AFE5-A28937F04BD8>.<2> resuming, timeouts(60.0, 604800.0) QOS(0x19) Voucher <private>
default    13:45:20.650280-0600    appstored    [Telemetry]: Activity <nw_activity 12:2 [8861910E-6C9C-4029-8C30-FB15A400CDE9] (reporting strategy default)> on Task <B3B892EF-AF0E-4185-AFE5-A28937F04BD8>.<2> was not selected for reporting
default    13:45:20.650562-0600    appstored    Task <B3B892EF-AF0E-4185-AFE5-A28937F04BD8>.<2> {strength 0, tls 4, ct 0, sub 0, sig 1, ciphers 0, bundle 1, builtin 0}
default    13:45:20.650599-0600    appstored    Task <B3B892EF-AF0E-4185-AFE5-A28937F04BD8>.<2> now using Connection 2319
default    13:45:20.654134-0600    fitcored    [1031] <private>::<private>
default    13:45:20.655855-0600    appstored    Task <B3B892EF-AF0E-4185-AFE5-A28937F04BD8>.<2> sent request, body S 592
default    13:45:20.656338-0600    CommCenter    #I querying acount name
default    13:45:20.656497-0600    accountsd    "<private> (<private>) received"
default    13:45:20.657079-0600    backboardd     [1.26.0]     +[ASEProcessing shouldEnhanceWidth:height:destinationWidth:destinationHeight:]: src={ 1242w x 2688h }, dest={ 1240w x 2683h }, aseFunctionOnYesOffNo=1
default    13:45:20.658111-0600    fitcored    Storefront matches cache: <private>
```

I'm at a loss, any one have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

So after having tons of fun debugging this.

I've opened up a bug with firebase.

https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/issues/5955